# Setting Up A Standalone WiFi Network

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+

I am starting to use Kali Linux for penetration testing. To use it, I need a WiFi network. I don’t want to use my own network but instead, I want to use my Raspberry Pi to create a WiFi network that I can test.

I do not want my Pi to connect to my network at all. I only want it to create its own network. How should I do this?

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand, but if you set the pi up as an access point and don't connect the ethernet port, then it won't have any access to your network

Comment: I did say that I didn't want the Pi to connect to my network. I don't need an internet connection.

Comment: well, don't physically connect it to the network

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I don't have experience with Kali Linux. Have you  considered to use Raspbian instead? With it I could present several solutions for an access point.

Comment: I'm sorry if I conveyed it the wrong way - I only need an access point to use Kali Linux on another computer. I do want to use Raspbian.